# My Meteor subscription doesn't update after route change

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I have a collection, `questions`.

I'm sending the user from one route to another via FlowRouter.

**The first route makes use of ALL documents in `questions`, but only one field: `_id`.**

**The second route only needs ONE document but ALL fields.**

Despite making a new subscription in the second route, only the old `_id` field is accessible (until the user manually refreshes).

The first route's component subscribes like this:

```
getMeteorData() {
  const questionsHandle = Meteor.subscribe('questions')

  return {
    questions: Questions.find().fetch()
  }
}
```

The publication only publishes the `_id` field:

```
Meteor.publish('hspUserQuestionsFromPracticeSet', function() {
    return Questions.find({}, {fields: {_id: 1}})
})
```

The route change happens simply with `FlowRouter.go(newRoute)` (I'm using some updated version of Flowrouter-SSR).

The second route:

```
getMeteorData() {

    const questionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('questionById', this.props.questionId)

    return {
        question: Questions.findOne(),
        questionReady: questionHandle.ready()
    }
},
```

The second publication:

```
Meteor.publish('questionById', function(questionId) {
    return Questions.find({_id: questionId})
})
```

What happens is that all of the documents in `questions` are already subscribed to when the route switch happens, so `Questions.findOne()` finds the first document from that list. So I have both the wrong document and only one field.

How do I fix this? I have tried unsubscribing on `componentWillUnmount` with a new publication with only `this.stop()` in it, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you checking that the new subscription is ready before rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your are using [Data Loading In React](http://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/data-loading-react/).

Your first subscribe should have ready state like you did in the second so that you are sure you loaded the entire list when you display it.

```
getMeteorData() {
  const questionsHandle = Meteor.subscribe('questions')
  return {
    ready: questionsHandle.ready(),
    questions: Questions.find().fetch()
  }
}
```

You have forgotten to precise which question you want to display in your findOne.

```
getMeteorData() {
    const questionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('questionById', this.props.questionId)

    return {
        question: Questions.findOne(this.props.questionId),
        questionReady: questionHandle.ready()
    }
},
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. It still has only one field.

Comment: Yeah. If nothing else works, I guess I'll just load every field in the first route.

Comment: You could also check if your publish is really called and if it returns the doc with all its fields

Comment: It's fixed. It actually worked putting `this.props.questionId` inside the `findOne`, something I completely disregarded as I figured that would only fetch the right question but still the wrong fields. I have NO idea why it works, but it does.